# What's the naming convention of an object which was a REASON of a fired event?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

Imagine that you have different type of objects.
And if those objects are in a specific state, a NotificationMessage is created.

If you need to create a property that will return an object which was the Reason of a NotificationMessage, how would you name this property?

Or if I generalize this to a naming convention: What is the naming convention when it comes to name a variable that was the main reason of an event to be fired?

Comment: How about `Reason` or `Cause`? I don't think there's a widely used convention for this.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example?  Why would this property not be a property on the event args?

Comment: What do you mean by... reason?

Answer (score 3):

Usually in the called event you get the Sender object:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
```

You can use a Sender prefix so you dont get conflicts with the name convention of C#.

Comment: `Source` is also sometimes seen.